# In Django, how do I keep a running list of notifications for the user?

Tags: python, database, django, notifications, message

When the user clicks the "My Notifications" tab, I want him to see a list of **new and old** notifications and the time that the action happened. That means, the notifications must be stored, and must even have a cursor to be paged through.

Does the Django message framework do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting [Django messages framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to fit with your requirement would be a big deviation from the way the framework works.

I would strongly recommend *not* to use the framework for this particular use-case since creating a simple Django model (User FK, Notification, created datetimestamp) would be a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as Siddharth rightly mentioned, you can't use the builtin framework to do this, as this is a big deviation from what it is intended to do.

But, there is an app for that. [django-notification](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification) app does precisely that!